# Add ability to filter search results by rep

Tags: feature-request, search

Similar to how we have `views:` & `votes:` option, It'd be immensely helpful if there was an option to filter search results by Rep ( `rep:`). That way we can search for posts containing "PLZZ HALP ME!!!111" and bring up those posts by users having not more than `n` rep.

Going through the /review route, it's obvious that most non-answers are drive-by "this worked!" or "I have this problem, please help me!" sort of posts. Having this search option will help filter these posts faster and help Stack Exchange maintain high quality answers.

Answer (score 2):

For moderating I'd prefer to use separate tools, specifically crafted for it.

In particular, you might find useful [new posts by new users](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-user-posts) page. It has much wider selection than "first answers" or "low quality posts" tabs and many of those posts have a room for improvement.

Comment: I'm aware of those, but can't use them on SO since I don't have the required privileges

Comment: @Sathya Well, that would be a good reason to request relaxed access to some of mod functionality (or maybe move it to /review). Seems much easier than duplicating it somewhere else :)